# How to trim last four character from the input in bash shell?

Tags: c++, bash, compilation, command, clang

I intend to automate compile and run process in C++, I wrote the following code as `compile-run.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
clang++ $1.cpp -o $1.out && ./$1.out
```

I put this compile-run.sh in /usr/local/bin for global usage,
and when I type the command `compile-run.sh XXX.cpp`, it intend to compile and run the specified cpp file. But the problem now is I have to manually removed "`.cpp`" in the command.

Is there any way to trim the last X number of character and assign to a variable in general?
Is there any way to trim the `.cpp` and apply trimmed $1 in the code?
Is there better way to automate compile and run process?

Comment: Define a new variable `trimmed=${1%.cpp}` (that removes the suffix `.cpp` if present), and use it instead of `$1`. Note: **you should use a Makefile and not a bash script for this task!**

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf is there any way to trim the last X number of character in general?

Comment: Sure: `trimmed=${variable::-4}` would work. But anyway, **use a Makefile for this task!**

Comment: Got it, thank you @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, an ugly way could be by using something like:

```
#! /bin/bash
filename=$1
temp="${filename%%.cpp}"
clang++ $temp.cpp -o $temp.out && ./$temp.out
```

another way, if you want to trim the last 4 characters whatever the last part is:

```
#! /bin/bash
filename=$1
temp="${filename::-4}"
clang++ $temp.cpp -o $temp.out && ./$temp.out
```

but for substrings you could also use cut: ie. https://stackabuse.com/substrings-in-bash/

Comment: Great! Is there anyway to trim last several character of the input variable in general?

Comment: I've updated that part. However, although outside the scope, I'd go with just spliting based on '.' then based on extension I'd call clang++ or something else, and throu an error otherwise.